# Bittrex Public API Confusion

Tags: php, api, public

I am a complete newbie here so apologies if I am asking a stupid question. I am trying to extract data from Bittrex's public API, specifically "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets".

I have had success obtaining data from other APIs by doing this, which prints out the top 20 coins:

```
$coinMarket = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=20";
$marketData = json_decode(file_get_contents($coinMarket), true);

for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
    $coins = $marketData[$i]["symbol"];
    print_r($coins);
}
```

When I try the same thing with the Bittrex API listed above, I just get the following repeated 20 times (with the offset number incremented by 1 each time):

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\BittrexBot.php on line
>   37

I've looked at what the two API calls actually return, and although very similar, the Bittrex data contains extra initial information which may be the culprit (this is just the first coin retrieved):

Bittrex:

```
Array ( 
    [success] => 1 [message] => [result] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => Array ( [MarketName] => BITCNY-BTC [High] => 30998.99999966 [Low] => 27727.54234112 [Volume] => 4.32110365 [Last] => 28007.61852638 [BaseVolume] => 127223.448106 [TimeStamp] => 2017-08-15T12:03:57.393 [Bid] => 27450.26691772 [Ask] => 28290.52376401 [OpenBuyOrders] => 186 [OpenSellOrders] => 47 [PrevDay] => 28853.26999991 [Created] => 2015-12-11T06:31:40.653
        )
```

CoinMarketCap:

```
Array 
        ( 
            [0] => Array ( [id] => bitcoin [name] => Bitcoin [symbol] => BTC [rank] => 1 [price_usd] => 4129.24 [price_btc] => 1.0 [24h_volume_usd] => 2984050000.0 [market_cap_usd] => 68165233778.0 [available_supply] => 16507937.0 [total_supply] => 16507937.0 [percent_change_1h] => 0.32 [percent_change_24h] => -1.73 [percent_change_7d] => 20.58 [last_updated] => 1502800149 
        )
```

Is the extra **Array ( [success] => 1 [message] => [result] =>** at the start of the returned data from Bittrex my issue? Or is it something unrelated to the returned data and rather how I am handling it?

For reference the code I attempt to use when accessing the Bittrex API is as follows:

```
$coinMarket = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
$marketData = json_decode(file_get_contents($coinMarket), true);

for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
    $coins = $marketData[$i]["MarketName"];
    print_r($coins);
}
```

Any assistance or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: The data returned by bittrex is different so you need to use different keys to access it correctly.

Comment: CoinmarketCaps returns information about coins while BitTrex getmarketsummaries returns information about trading pairs. The difference between those can be huge, depending on what you do with the data

Answer (score 1):

It's not that there is something  at the start of returned data, array's
don't work like  that; but in fact  they are very different  and must be
accessed in a different manner.

In *CoinMarketCap*,  the data was given  in the first dimension  of your
array. In *Bittrex*, data is being given inside a `result` array, so you
must access it accordingly:

```
$coins = $marketData['result'][$i]['MarketName'];
```

To help debugging these cases, when  you `print_r()` an array in HTML it
is good to echo a `<pre>` tag first:

```
echo '<pre>';

# or

<pre>
<?php # php code
```

This will  preserve whitespace  and make the  format far  more readable.
That or `var_dump()` will help you visualising the array better. Example
with your data:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MarketName] => BITCNY-BTC
                    [High] => 30998.99999966
                    [Low] => 27450.26691772
                    [Volume] => 4.11387066
                    [Last] => 28290.52376401
                    [BaseVolume] => 121183.63341716
                    [TimeStamp] => 2017-08-15T13:28:16.543
                    [Bid] => 27450.267
                    [Ask] => 28290.52376325
                    [OpenBuyOrders] => 186
                    [OpenSellOrders] => 47
                    [PrevDay] => 29041.02993787
                    [Created] => 2015-12-11T06:31:40.653
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [MarketName] => BTC-1ST
                    [High] => 0.00019299
                    [Low] => 0.00015028
                    [Volume] => 680348.58729147
               ....................................
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. However, it still doesn't appear to work and has exactly the same issue as before. The other reply suggests a method that does work (and I think I understand why) but I'd love to understand why the method you're suggesting does not work. It just does not like $coins = $marketData[$i]['result']['MarketName']

Comment: @Mattaus I am very sorry, but I made a mistake and wrote the array access incorrectly. I reversed positions of the iterating variable and the `result` array, which should come first. Please check the updated answer. Regarding your comment on the other answer, that thinking is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To access data within the response you might look at something like this:

```
$url='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets';
$data=file_get_contents( $url );
$json=json_decode( $data );

$result=$json->result;
foreach( $result as $i => $obj ){
    echo $obj->MarketName,'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure why the other suggested method is not working, but this does appear to work. Can you confirm my understanding of the code is correct? $json is the entire extracted data. $result is then the 'result' sub-array extracted from the $json data (basically stripping off the outer array). In the loop we are incrementally taking lowest level array within this "sub-array" and assigning it to $obj. Finally we are echoing the 'MarketName' section of this data. In my case I will just assign the market name to a variable for later use.

Comment: in a nutshell - yes.